# How to set a value of a non-mapped parameter of an entity during fetch

Tags: c#, entity-framework, objectcontext

I am using Database-First Entity Framework and I have modified Model.tt file a bit for my needs. Now, all of my entities are inherited from the following class:

```
public class EntityBase
{
    public string CreateUser { get; set; }
    public string CancelUser { get; set; }
}
```

such as

```
public partial class Depot : EntityBase
```

And all of my entities do have a integer type `CreateUserId` and nullable-integer type `CancelUserId` properties on them. I am also using a custom class `MyContext` which inherits from, so I can interrupt processes.

Suppose that I have all valid users in cache, and during any query execution which retrieves data from the database I want to interfere, read the value from `CreateUserId` property, find the matching User from cache, and finally update the value of `CreateUser` property which is inherited from the `EntityBase` class with the username property of the matching `User` object.

And I want to do this for all my entities of which are fetched from database even in the same query or not.

Is this possible. If so, how could I implement it?

Regards.

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412552/custom-entity-materialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Augusto Barreto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1454888/augusto-barreto) stated, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412552/custom-entity-materialization) post proposes to use the `ObjectMaterialized`. I have just implemented it in my Context as follows:

```
public class TContext : ObjectContext
{
    private IQueryable<User> _allUsers;

     public MyContext()
        : base("name=MyEntities", "MyEntities")
    {
        if (this._allUsers == null || _allUsers.Count() == 0)
        {
            LoadAllUsers();
        }
    }

    private void LoadAllUsers()
    {
        ObjectSet<User> userSet = this.CreateObjectSet<User>();
        _allUsers = userSet.Where(x => x.Id > 0);
    }

    private void MyContext_ObjectMaterialized(object sender, ObjectMaterializedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_allUsers != null & _allUsers.Count() > 0)
        {
            Type type = e.Entity.GetType();
            // Create user info
            PropertyInfo piBase = type.GetProperty("CreateUser");
            PropertyInfo piObj = type.GetProperty("CreateUserId");
            if (piBase != null && piObj != null)
            {
                int userId = (int)piObj.GetValue(e.Entity);
                User createUser = _allUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == userId);
                if (createUser != null)
                {
                    piBase.SetValue(e.Entity, createUser.Username);
                }
            }

            piBase = type.GetProperty("CancelUser");
            piObj = type.GetProperty("CancelUserId");
            if (piBase != null && piObj != null)
            {
                int? userId = (int?)piObj.GetValue(e.Entity);
                if (userId.HasValue)
                {
                    User cancelUser = _allUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == userId.Value);
                    if (cancelUser != null)
                    {
                        piBase.SetValue(e.Entity, cancelUser.Username);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```